# MLR - getBMRModels - How to access each model from the benchmark result

Tags: r, machine-learning, mlr

When running a [Benchmark Experiment](http://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/benchmark_experiments/) on multiple algorithms, with tuning wrappers etc. there will be multiple models returned for each algorithm.

What is the canonical way, or an effective way, of extracting each individual tuned model (with the various hyperparameters) so that they can be accessed individually, and used individually for predictions without all the baggage of other models etc.?

Reproducible Example

```
# Required Packages
# Load required packages
library(mlr)
#library(dplyr)
library(parallelMap)
library(parallel)

# Algorithms
iterations = 10L
cv_iters = 2
### classif.gamboost ############################################################################################################################
classif_gamboost = makeLearner("classif.gamboost", predict.type="prob")

##The wrappers are presented in reverse order of application
###One-Hot Encoding
classif_gamboost = makeDummyFeaturesWrapper(classif_gamboost, method = "1-of-n")
###Missing Data Imputation
classif_gamboost = makeImputeWrapper(classif_gamboost, classes = list(numeric = imputeConstant(-99999), integer = imputeConstant(-99999), factor = imputeConstant("==Missing==")), dummy.type = "numeric", dummy.classes = c("numeric","integer"))

##### Tuning #####
inner_resamp = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters=cv_iters)
ctrl = makeTuneControlRandom(maxit=iterations)
hypss = makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam("baselearner", values=c("btree")), #,"bols","btree","bbs"
  makeIntegerParam("dfbase", lower = 1, upper = 5),
  makeDiscreteParam("family", values=c("Binomial")),
  makeDiscreteParam("mstop", values=c(10,50,100,250,500,1000))
)
classif_gamboost = makeTuneWrapper(classif_gamboost, resampling = inner_resamp, par.set = hypss, control = ctrl, measures = list(auc, logloss, f1, ber, acc, bac, mmce, timetrain), show.info=TRUE)
### classif.gamboost ############################################################################################################################

### Random Forest ############################################################################################################################
classif_rforest = makeLearner("classif.randomForestSRC", predict.type="prob")

##The wrappers are presented in reverse order of application
###One-Hot Encoding
classif_rforest = makeDummyFeaturesWrapper(classif_rforest, method = "1-of-n")
###Missing Data Imputation
classif_rforest = makeImputeWrapper(classif_rforest, classes = list(numeric = imputeConstant(-99999), integer = imputeConstant(-99999), factor = imputeConstant("==Missing==")), dummy.type = "numeric", dummy.classes = c("numeric","integer"))

##### Tuning #####
inner_resamp = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters=cv_iters)
ctrl = makeTuneControlRandom(maxit=iterations)
hypss = makeParamSet(
  makeIntegerParam("mtry", lower = 1, upper = 30)
  ,makeIntegerParam("ntree", lower = 100, upper = 500)
  ,makeIntegerParam("nodesize", lower = 1, upper = 100)
)
classif_rforest = makeTuneWrapper(classif_rforest, resampling = inner_resamp, par.set = hypss, control = ctrl, measures = list(auc, logloss, f1, ber, acc, bac, mmce, timetrain), show.info=TRUE)
### Random Forest ############################################################################################################################

trainData = mtcars
target_feature = "am"
training_task_name = "trainingTask"
trainData[[target_feature]] = as.factor(trainData[[target_feature]])
trainTask = makeClassifTask(id=training_task_name, data=trainData, target=target_feature, positive=1, fixup.data="warn", check.data=TRUE)

train_indices = 1:25
valid_indices = 26:32
outer_resampling = makeFixedHoldoutInstance(train_indices, valid_indices, nrow(trainData))

no_of_cores = detectCores()
parallelStartSocket(no_of_cores, level=c("mlr.tuneParams"), logging = TRUE)
lrns = list(classif_gamboost, classif_rforest)
res = benchmark(tasks = trainTask, learners = lrns, resampling = outer_resampling, measures = list(logloss, auc, f1, ber, acc, bac, mmce, timetrain), show.info = TRUE, models = TRUE, keep.pred = FALSE)
parallelStop()

models = getBMRModels(res)
models
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to train a new model with the function `train` to further proceed, for example for predicting new data points. You would have used the complete dataset for training and not only a part.

If you want to use your models from the benchmarking, you can get them via `getBMRModels` as you already posted and then just get the specific model that you want. (Get the specific list element with models$ ...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Few questions. It would seem as part of the Benchmark Experiment I have already trained multiple models with various hyperparameters. How is each individual model accessed? In terms of retraining the model with the "best" hyperparameters, fair enough, how do you suggest getting the best hyperparameters out of the benchmark result?

Comment: In your `models` object the different models are saved. You can access the tuning results via `getTuneResults`. You could for example get the tuning result of your first model, first learner and the first cross-validation iteration via:  `getTuneResult(mods[[1]][[1]][[1]])`
Maybe there is even a more elegant solution/function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That appears to only access 1 model, how do I access the other cross validation iterations?

Comment: Just change the numbers to `getTuneResult(mods[[1]][[1]][[2]])` and so on... It is all saved in lists.

Comment: That's what I thought too. That doesn't appear to work. Only [[1]] model is accessible, any other numbers throw a subscript out of bounds unfortunately.